How to check transactions on blockchain
I am assuming all BTC blockchain explorers are either centralized services or hosted on servers which are a centralized service. In the case of something going wrong with these centralized servers and if these explorers are not accessible then how to check transactions on the blockchain. Till now all I know about verifying transactions on the blockchain means going to the explorers. What other ways are there to see blockchain activities?

You can run any open-source blockchain explorer on your own PC. Typically by compiling source code
You can run a program such as Bitcoin core without using its wallet features and turn on relevant features such as transaction indexing. This is less than ideal but might suffice for some basic requirements.
A watch-only wallet is useful if you only need to track transactions related to a limited set of public keys.
Any fully synchronised full-node wallet can tell you everything you need to know about the blockchain records relating to your own transactions.

Related

Blockchain Explorer for local full node
How can I take a "snapshot" of the bitcoin blockchain and analyze it?
Is blockchain.com the only place where you can see the blockchain?
Example code in answer to What are the mean, median, range, limits and trends in the size of coinbase transactions?

